# Scrollbottom js not working in Firefox, Chrome, Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I've used scrollbottom javascript with JQuery (1.3.2/jquery.min.js) to scroll to a particular div in the below of the page. It is working fine in IE 8 & 9 but it this functionility is not working in Firefox, Chrome, Safari. I mean scrolling functionality is working but the div text is not showing. I used like:

```
<a href="#about">About Us</a>   Top div

<a name="about">Description</a>  Bottom div
```

Any idea to make it workable in Firefox. Appreciate for your kind advice. Thank you.

Comment: Use latest jquery library.. and see this for reference http://jsfiddle.net/Dineshkani/kga8b/9/. Your code also works perfectly http://jsfiddle.net/Dineshkani/kga8b/12/

Answer (score 0):

I don't see in the Fiddle above the code for scrolling down, but you can try like in [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kga8b/13/). But that's correct, you should use the latest jQuery version.

What I added in the JS:

```
$('#firstdiv').on("click", function(){
    $('html, body').animate({"scrollTop" : $(document).height() - $(window).height()});
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the kind info, I've updated but still the bottom div's text is not showing in FF, Chrome etc. Please any other way. Thank you.